# svn soft links from svn:externals?

Tags: svn

i am using svn repository. on directory A i have

- libSomeLib.so -> libSomeLib.so.1
- libSomeLib.so.1
  libSomeLib.so is soft link to libSomeLib.so.1

when i run 
`> svn co A` i get the soft link as i expect. 
i have directory B which has svn:externals property to check out directory A. the problem is that once i run

```
svn co B
```

i get directory A, but libSomeLib.so is no longet the soft link. how can i solve this issue ?
i am using svn client version 1.6.6